# In need of a Javascript Delay

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could modify this code so that it has a 2 second delay before the function become active:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframe_onload()
{
var theWaitCell = document.getElementById('Wait1');
theWaitCell.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function iframe_onload()
{
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        var theWaitCell = document.getElementById('Wait1');
        theWaitCell.style.display = "none";
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**setTimeout()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function:

**Syntax:**

```
// Fires yourFunction() after delayInMilliseconds has elapsed
// Note: You pass the function object as the first parameter
// do NOT execute the function here (i.e. omit the "()")

setTimeout(yourFunction, delayInMilliseconds);
```

**Usage:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

//Timeout Function (2000 ~ 2 Seconds)
setTimeout(iframe_onload, 2000);

//Action Function
function iframe_onload() {
    var theWaitCell = document.getElementById('Wait1');
    theWaitCell.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't "yourFunction()" and "iframe_onload()" execute immediately?

I think you want "setTimeout(iframe_onload, 2000);"

Comment: That is correct - I believe the edit has been made :) Thanks to Beez and Ivo for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(
    function ()
    {
        var theWaitCell = document.getElementById('Wait1');
        theWaitCell.style.display = "none";
    },
    2000 // The 2nd arg is delay in milliseconds
);
</script>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want a nice delay you should use jquery but you could also call the function in the input with setTimeout();

```
<form>
<input type ="button lets say" onclick = "setTimeout('iframe_onload()', 2000);"/>
</form>
```